# Moving Drive Group without losing Data

Tags: raid

I am testing a scenario of moving drives without losing data as follow .

I have SERVER A with 2 Drive Groups :

Drive Group : 0 , RAID 1

2 drives  System drives

Drive Group : 1 , RAID 6

8 drives Data drives

I have installed another server "SERVER B" with the same specification and installed everything identical to SERVER A (Same RAID schema ).

Now i wanted to move all 8 Data drives from SERVER A and plug in SERVER B "simulating failure in server 1 system disk and mother board" .

After booting Server B , The Data drives are shown as Foreign but i couldn't import or clear configuration ?

Any suggestion why i cant import or clear the configuration and boot Server B ?
[image: Foreign View]

[image: Foreign config import]

[image: Foreign config clear]

I tried to clear cache but still the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform the test after contacting supermicro support , here's the procedure :

1. The RAID controller need to be identical in both servers. This can be verified in SAS MegaRAID Configuration Utility.
2. Completely power-off both servers .
3. Move all 8 data disks from Server A and plugged them into Server B;
4. It's important to keep the disks in the same order as they were originally.
5. Power on Server B and access SAS MegaRAID Configuration Utility to verify the status.

> Interestingly the drives didn't appear as foreign "In my case", it just recognized as drive group 1 ; therefore, for this case i didn't have to import foreign config .

6. After the system finish booting, it should automatically start the background initializing for VD1.

> #To verify it, run the following command:
>
> /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/storcli64 /c0 /v1 show bgi

- SuperMicro Feedback :

> When you plug in the drives with same storage controller, at the first reboot you should see message asking if you want to import foreign configurations. If so, then please follow the screen on how to import and this may import existing RAID without any issue.

```
IMPORTANT
Do not clear the configurations! If you do it, you will clear all the DATA .

Make sure to not mix any drives.
```